# Get all tags inside a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Newbie in javascript.

Suppose I have this html

```
    <html>
    <div id = "div1">
      <table>
       <tr><td>Name</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Password</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id = "div2">
      <input name="place" value=""/>
      <input name="place" value=""/>
    </div>
    </html>
```

But I want to retrieve all the tags and elements of a div in "div1".
So elements that will be retrieved will be

```
          <table>
           <tr><td>Name</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Password</td></tr>
          </table>
```

Not only the data.

Comment: '$(#div1)' for the entire dom object. Or '$(#div1).html()' for innerHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use this in your code you will be able to get the table which your saying

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, congratulation on getting started on JS. It's a beautiful scripting language. Next, I would advise you, to make your life simpler while you should play around with a pure Javascript syntax, it will make your life a whole lot easier if you get started on a library, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Mootools](http://mootools.net/). JQuery is my preference, mootools is more of a framework.

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;
```

in jquery is as elemental as `$(#div1)` or `$(#div1).html()`. Have fun learning!